# How to add new variables in Search Query - ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created a query search in ADF from business components(drag and drop - all queriable attributes ), and i need to add a new variable from another table to this search query, can any body help me ?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to query the other table ? why don't you join the two entities in the view object ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new VO that will have all the properties that you want to query on. A VO can combine data from two tables also.